# FCM 17.3.4 push notification icon is not shown

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am devloping Android App with Firebase Cloud Messaging 17.3.4.

On Android 8.0, push notification icon is not shown.

According to Firebase release notes, this bug has been fixed from version 12.0.0.

Of course, I properly set the notification icon in Manifest in the following.

```
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
```

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

(Optional) From Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher, notification channels are supported and recommended. FCM provides a default notification channel with basic settings. If you prefer to create and use your own default channel, set default_notification_channel_id to the ID of your notification channel object as shown; FCM will use this value whenever incoming messages do not explicitly set a notification channel. To learn more, see Manage notification channels.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
    android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
```

Reference[enter link description here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?authuser=0)